# Export to single HTML with embedded images using Jasper Report

Tags: java, html, jsp, reporting, jasper-reports

Can Jasper Report export to single HTML with embedded images?

I have output of jasper reports as single Excel file, PDF, RTF.
But multiplay HTML files.
It trouble for me to manage not single report file, but many files and folders in HTML case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A solution:

```
Map<String, String> images = new HashMap<>();

SimpleHtmlExporterOutput simpleHtmlExporterOutput = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(outputStream);
simpleHtmlExporterOutput.setImageHandler(new HtmlResourceHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleResource(String id, byte[] data) {
                System.err.println("id" + id);
                images.put(id, "data:image/jpg;base64," + Base64.encodeBytes(data));
            }

            @Override
            public String getResourcePath(String id) {
                return images.get(id);
            }
        });
```

Full code:

```
package com.test.report;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.HtmlResourceHandler;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleExporterInput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleHtmlExporterOutput;
import net.sf.jasperreports.export.SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.olap4j.impl.Base64;

import com.artech.reportservice.reports.ReportType;

public class ReportTest {
    Map<String, String> images = new HashMap<>();

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        // String outFileName = "test.html";

        String xmlFileLocation = "/Users/skozlic/dev/VacationToolProject/wokspace/ReportService/src/test/resources/machineReportTestFile.xml";

        JasperReport reportTemplate = ReportType.MPM.getReportTemplate();
        JRXmlDataSource jrxmlds = ReportType.MPM.getReportDateSource(xmlFileLocation);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportTemplate, null, jrxmlds);

        HtmlExporter exporterHTML = new HtmlExporter();
        SimpleExporterInput exporterInput = new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint);
        exporterHTML.setExporterInput(exporterInput);
        SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration reportExportConfiguration = new SimpleHtmlReportConfiguration();

        exporterHTML.setConfiguration(reportExportConfiguration);
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        SimpleHtmlExporterOutput simpleHtmlExporterOutput = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(outputStream);
        simpleHtmlExporterOutput.setImageHandler(new HtmlResourceHandler() {

            @Override
            public void handleResource(String id, byte[] data) {
                System.err.println("id" + id);
                images.put(id, "data:image/jpg;base64," + Base64.encodeBytes(data));
            }

            @Override
            public String getResourcePath(String id) {
                return images.get(id);
            }
        });
        exporterHTML.setExporterOutput(simpleHtmlExporterOutput);

        exporterHTML.exportReport();
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("test.html"), outputStream.toByteArray());

    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer I've come across to handle images when exporting a report as HTML to an output stream, thanks!  Other answers had me adding an ImageServlet to my web.xml but this one is done all with code and is using the latest Jasper API so there are no deprecation warnings.

Comment: Do you have the Jasper XML you used for your exemple ?

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with Word report ? We have a HTML with img in base64 encoding inside the HTML, we would like to create a report in word

Comment: is there any way to embed multiple image by  manipulating resource id ?

Comment: Hi, Any running example. Please share here, i am stuck with the same.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that jasper reports has built in support for this, so you'd have to roll out your own implementation. You can use this technique to embed them images.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K... " />
```

So first you'd use java's xml parser to find all the image tags in the html  http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/. Then you'd read all the files, convert them to base64 string http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/736/ and replace the `img`'s src with the above format.

Comment: what about the flag JasperExportManager.exportReportToXmlFile(jasperPrint, isEmbeddingImages); maybe the is something similar for HTML

Comment: @kozla13 update your original answer with the additional information instead of adding another one.

Answer (score 1):

I was grappling with this for the last few days, and finally solved it. My reports run in a web environment, so I was able to use the `net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.ImageServlet` to serve the images. This requires a bit of setting up though.

1. Use the `JRImageRenderer` to render the images in the report itself:

   ```
   <image ... >
     ...
     <imageExpression>
       <![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRImageRenderer.getInstance($F{image_data})]]>
     </imageExpression>
   </image>
   ```

   where `$F{image_data}` is the binary image data.
2. When exporting the report, nominate `WebResourceHandler` as the HTML resource handler.

   ```
   SimpleHtmlExporterOutput exporterOutput = new SimpleHtmlExporterOutput(byteArrayOutputStream);
   HtmlResourceHandler imageHandler = new WebHtmlResourceHandler("https://www.mywebsite.com/report/image?image={0}");
   exporterOutput.setImageHandler(imageHandler);
   exporter.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput);
   exporter.exportReport();
   ```

   To check, if you now generate an HTML report and inspect the source, you should see something like `<img href="http://www.mywebsite.com/report/image?image=img_0_0_2.png" />`.
3. Now you need to activate the `ImageServlet`, so it can
   intercept and fulfill the image requests. Add the following block to
   your `web.xml` file:

   ```
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>JasperImageServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>net.sf.jasperreports.j2ee.servlets.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>JasperImageServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/report/image</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```

   (Note that the `/report/image` path matches the URL argument we passed to the `WebHtmlResourceHandler`.)

   Start the webserver and try to generate an HTML report once more. It still won't work of course, but copy the image's URL and paste it into your browser. You should get an error message from the `ImageServlet` that

   > No JasperPrint documents found on the HTTP session.
4. The last thing to do is to add the `JasperPrint` object to the session, so the `ImageServlet` knows which image to serve. In JSP that can be done like this:

   ```
   JasperPrint jasperPrint = ...
   HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
   session.setAttribute(ImageServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, jasperPrint);
   ```

Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by ilia, until recently data uri was not cross compatible, so you HAD to save multiple files. Might want to file an enhancement request with Jasper to request an option to save html as one file with embedded data uris

Answer (score 0):

A minor improvement to Dave Jarvis solution.

Instead of hard-coding the mime type in

```
images.put(id, "data:image/jpg;base64," + Base64.encodeBytes(data));
```

You can try to discover the mime type like this:

```
// Find out the mime type
final ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream( data );
final String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream( bis );
// Convert to an embedded "data" url.
final String base64Data = "data:"+mimeType+";base64,"+Base64.encodeBytes( data );
imagesMap.put( id, base64Data );
```