# Alternative of JRHtmlExporter - how to use HtmlExporteroutput.getImageHandler() method?

Tags: java, html, jasper-reports

Earlier I was using jasperreports-5.5.0,  but now I am switching to JasperReports-6.8. The below code i was using for JasperReports 5.5.0.

```
JRHtmlExporter exporter = new JRHTMLExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_OUTPUT_IMAGES_TO_DIR, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_DIR_NAME, imageDir);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IMAGES_URI, imageUri);
```

As ***JRHmlExporterParameter*** is deprecated now, the HtmlExporteroutput.getImageHandler() method should be used
instead of it.

I am trying to implement the same, but I am not able to find any sample example.

can anyone please give any sample example.

Comment: Duplicate of [JRHtmlExporter is deprecated now. How to define the path for saving images?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43763810/876298)

Comment: Another sample of usage: [Export to single HTML with embedded images using Jasper Report](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6942373/876298)

Comment: Hi Alex. Thanks for your answer. From the above two link i am not able to find any example related to IS_OUTPUT_IMAGES_TO_DIR, it will be helpfull if you can give an example for the same.